# How to filter measure in the Filter function by multiple items from the same hierarchy

Tags: mdx

I am creating an application that generates `MDX` queries. I stuck with implementing a scenario when the user uses the [Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx) function and, in the logical expression, the user wants to slice a measure by multiple members from the same hierarchy.

Here is a real example: there is a cube **Education** with the following dimensions and measures

- **Dimensions**: Student, School Year
- **Measures**: Student Attendance, Student Infractions

The user wants to see Student Attendance of students that had one or more Student Infractions in school year 2010 and 2011.

I need to accomplish this using the Filter function so I wrote the query below

```
SELECT [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
FROM (
  SELECT 
    FILTER(
        [Student].[Student].[Student].Members, 
          (
            [Measures].[Student Infractions], 
            AGGREGATE(
                {
                  [School Year].[School Year].&[2010]
                 ,[School Year].[School Year].&[2011]
                }
            )
          ) > 1
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Education]
)
```

The problem is that when this query gets executed, it throws 
`'Query (4, 55) The Tuple function expects a tuple set expression for the 2 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.'`

It looks like it is impossible to use the [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx) function inside the Filter function. Is there any way how to get the query working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra square bracket as marked below, which is part of the 2nd argument of the tuple - this might be the reason for the error message:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
FROM (
  SELECT 
    FILTER(
        [Student].[Student].[Student].Members, 
          (
            [Measures].[Student Infractions], 
            AGGREGATE(
                {
                  [School Year].[School Year].&[2010]
                 ,[School Year].[School Year].&[2011]]   //<<<EXTRA BRACKET !
                }
            )
          ) > 1
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Education]
)
```

All the logic could just go in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query and get rid of the `sub-select`:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
FROM   [Education]
WHERE  (
        Filter
          (
            [Student].[Student].[Student].MEMBERS
           ,
              AGGREGATE(
                 {[School Year].[School Year].&[2010] , [School Year].[School Year].&[2011]}
                 ,[Measures].[Student Infractions]    
          )
        > 1
       );
```

---

**Edit**

You original query without `AGGREGATE` but tested against AdvWrks and seems to execute ok:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      Filter
      (
        [Student].[Student].[Student].MEMBERS
       ,
          [Measures].[Student Infractions]
        * 
          ([School Year].[School Year].&[2010] + [School Year].[School Year].&[2011])
      )
    > 1 ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Education]
);
```

This was the AdvWrks equivalent script I wrote - it runs ok:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Filter
    (
      [Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory].MEMBERS
     ,
          [Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity]
        * 
          (
            [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
          + 
            [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
          )
      > 1
    ) ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

---

**Edit2**

Ok - I should have read `MSDN` more thoroughly! This is the syntax for `AGGREGATE`:

> Aggregate(Set_Expression [ ,Numeric_Expression ])

Following this advice...

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      Filter
      (
        [Student].[Student].[Student].MEMBERS
       ,
          AGGREGATE(
            {[School Year].[School Year].&[2010] , [School Year].[School Year].&[2011]}
            ,[Measures].[Student Infractions]    
      )
    > 1 ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Education]
);
```

Comment: whytheq, the extra bracket was a typo. Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the query in my question. I cannot use the slicer since the select should work in sub-select. Slicer is not allowed in sub-selects. I don;t think the two last queries from your comment do what I need because the slicer also filters the Student Attendance by 2010,2011 school year. Anyway, thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @Alex ok - I added a reworking of your original script. I've used the operator `+` rather than the function `AGGREGATE` and it seems happy now. I'm unsure of reasons why one works and not the other.

Comment: @Alex I've also deleted one of my earlier attempts - as you point out `WHERE` is not allowed in sub-select. I have corrected the 2nd script in my post so that it uses the `WHERE` clause correctly to return your numbers ok. Also I sussed out the correct syntax for `AGGREGATE` and added the script at the end of my post.

Comment: whytheq, thanks for your solution. I got my  query working with the Aggregate function based on your example. The only issue I have now is that the Aggregate function cannot be used on calculated measures so I cannot implement a generic solution to the scenario, but at least this is a good start point for me.

Comment: whytheq, regarding your first EDIT, it executes Ok, but I got wrong numbers, after moving this part    [Measures].[Student Infractions]
        * 
          ([School Year].[School Year].&[2010] + [School Year].[School Year].&[2011])
          ) to WITH MEMBER area  I got an Infinite Loop Error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` clause

```
With member hadInfraction 
as (
   iif(sum( {[School Year].[School Year].&[2010],[School Year].[School Year].&[2011]},
            [Measures].[Student Infractions]) > 1, 1,0)
)
   SELECT {[Measures].[Student Attendance] } ON 0,
     {[Student].[Student].[Student].Members}
Having [Measures].[hadInfraction] =1
On 1
From Education
```

I barely use FILTER function - it is slow and not flexible. `Having` allows you to filter any set based on any calculated member you want.

EDIT: As long as you need MDX generation, then you should consider using the general approach of all MDX browsers (Excel, SSMS etc.):

User supplies [School Year].[School Year].&[2010],[School Year].[School Year].&[2011] as Cube slice, while you also need Measure Filter.

- first, generate sub-select for each [School Year], selecting only
  Years:

  ...
  from (

  select {[School Year].[School Year].&[2010],[School Year].[School Year].&[2011]} on 0 )

  from [Education]
- second, use HAVING or FILTER on the top-set to get what you need

The problem is you should construct additional calculated member by yourself, in general using `AGGREGATE` (in general you need default aggregation function). Thus, you will probably be able to shot 1 out of 100 possible scenarios for visually-programmed queries.

However, it is rare case when you MDX browser is smart enough to generate queries using both dimension filters and measure group member filters. Even heavy products like SSMS/Excel delegate this task to pure MDX code;

Comment: George, thanks for your reply.  I need a general solution for the tool I am working on. I cannot use Having because it cannot be used in sub-selects. Also I cannot use the SUM function because instead of Student Infractions there may be another measure with different aggregation type; The Filter function meets all my requirements except  filtering a measure by multiple members from the same hierarchy so I was hoping that there is a way how to get the Filter function working in my scenario.

Comment: You can use that member in filter also, but never in subselects, here you are limited to filters, sadly. Instead of SUM, use Aggregate. Also, tell me the purpose of subselect - you wont gain much performance compared to WHERE hete

Comment: George, thanks for the clarifications. The purpose of subselects is that I am implementing a tool that allows users to disaggregate data by adding more and more conditions and filters. Each disaggregation level represents a select statement with subselect of parent disaggregation level.

Answer (score 0):

Well why don't you add a measure in the cube for the years 2010 and 2011? Adding that would significantly reduce the complexity.

Final query can look like this:

```
WITH [Measures].[Student Attendance For Selected Years] AS
AGGREGATE(
                {
                  STRTOSET('[School Year].[School Year].&[2010]
                 ,[School Year].[School Year].&[2011]') ---STRTOSET function allows for this part to be a parameter
                },
                [Measures].[Student Infractions]
         )

SELECT [Measures].[Student Attendance] ON COLUMNS
 FROM [Education]
 WHERE FILTER([Student].[Student].children, [Measures].[Student Attendance For Selected Years]>1)
```

What you need to do is build the parameter and pass it onto the MDX's `STRTOSET` part. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92ccae0e-a764-49b5-a3a6-f0acd111372d/using-strtoset-in-a-parameterized-mdx-query?forum=sqlreportingservices) how `StrToSet` function is used with SSRS. You can try something similar.

Comment: I cannot add regular measures  to the cube because I am implementing a tool that generates MDX queries. Your example will not work if [Measures].[Student Infractions] is a calculated measure. This is a limitation of the Aggregate function

Comment: Go for a calculated member then. The `WITH` clause creates calculated member, which I have used in my answer.

Comment: Moreover `StrToSet` lets you add dynamic values of years. From what I am guessing, 2010 and 2011 are sample values, but as an end product, you would need to pass the years dynamically.

Comment: the calculated members defined in the with clause are not available in subselects. so I cannot use this approach.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but why are you hell bent on using sub-selects when there could be other solutions? My solution does not use sub select. Is it a constraint for you to MUST have one?

Comment: Sourav_Agasti, thanks for your help. Using subselects in my scenario seems logical and probably it is the MUST constraint. All MDX browsers I've seen use this approach. With subselects I can cover more than 95%  user scenarios.

Comment: I guess you are right. You have got two very good answers already. All the best!